# Can event be triggered on focus?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader [addInitialFiles](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html#addInitialFiles).

I use below code snippet to to trigger the uploader.addInitialFiles.

```
qq(document.getElementById("sectiontab1")).attach("click", function() {
    //uploader.addInitialFiles....  
});
```

Above function works great upon user 'click' on the TAB. My issue is that tabs are also activated NEXT button click (application specific). I can not attach above function to Next button click as NEXT button is generic (does not aware of uploader instance tied to each tab).

Essentially, I want to have something like below...focus event trigger. That way, uploader code is triggered on both cases (1. User click on TAB, 2.User click on NEXT,which gets focus on TAB by itself). But below function does not get triggered.

```
qq(document.getElementById("sectiontab1")).attach("focus", function() {
    //uploader.addInitialFiles....  
});
```

Is there anything that I missing that prevents 'focus' trigger?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4jFy.jpg) of app

Answer (score 0):

You can bind multiple events in jQuery by including each one separated by a space.

```
qq("#sectiontab1")..bind( "click focus", function() {
    //uploader.addInitialFiles....  
});
```

Comment: Does not work: .bind("click", .bind("click focus", .attach("click focus"